# ClassNotFoundException when working with Remote EJB in WebLogic 11g

Tags: java, ejb, weblogic

I could swear I've done this before, just not sure what I'm forgetting.  I receive class not found exceptions when working with Remote EJBs from a Java SE client talking to Weblogic 11g.

```
javax.naming.NamingException: Unhandled exception in lookup [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 257 completed: Maybe]
    at weblogic.corba.j2ee.naming.Utils.wrapNamingException(Utils.java:83)
    at weblogic.corba.j2ee.naming.ContextImpl.lookup(ContextImpl.java:291)
    at weblogic.corba.j2ee.naming.ContextImpl.lookup(ContextImpl.java:227)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 257 completed: Maybe
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.couldNotFindClass(ORBUtilSystemException.java:8260)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1013)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:879)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_abstract_interface(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:873)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_abstract_interface(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:863)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream.read_abstract_interface(CDRInputStream.java:269)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.util.Utility.readAbstractAndNarrow(Utility.java:948)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectField(IIOPInputStream.java:1992)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputClassFields(IIOPInputStream.java:2220)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1227)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:400)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:317)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:283)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1034)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:879)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream.read_value(CDRInputStream.java:249)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.corba.TCUtility.unmarshalIn(TCUtility.java:269)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.corba.AnyImpl.read_value(AnyImpl.java:559)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_any(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:739)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream.read_any(CDRInputStream.java:220)
    at weblogic.corba.cos.naming._NamingContextAnyStub.resolve_any(_NamingContextAnyStub.java:81)
    at weblogic.corba.j2ee.naming.ContextImpl.lookup(ContextImpl.java:267)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
    ... 26 more
```

Comment: +1 on this question. I have the same error.

Comment: Franz See: I ended up packaging the entire api and impl into a jar and deploy to the caller.  Shouldn't be that way, but seems to have worked.

Answer (score 0):

The  `vmcid: SUN  minor code: 257 completed: Maybe` makes me think its a version incompatibility -- that is, the client code and the rmi stubs are a different version than the server ejb code.

Answer (score 0):

You need `wlfullclient.jar` as stated in [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13717/basics.htm#i1072538)

> Prior to WebLogic Server 10.0, the `weblogic.jar` file was required for T3 and WLS-IIOP client applications to provide WebLogic Server-specific value-added features. For WebLogic Server 10.x and later releases, stand-alone client applications requiring these features use the `wlfullclient.jar` file instead of the `weblogic.jar` [...]
>
> You can generate the `wlfullclient.jar` file for client applications using the JarBuilder tool. [...]
>
> **Note:** Continuing to use `weblogic.jar` in client-side applications may result in a `ClassNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 0):

This comment is for developers who are facing the error: vmcid: SUN  minor code: 2xx with weblogic 12c+

I took this notes from (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS4QMC_9.5.0/com.ibm.help.install.cpqpostinstallation.doc/installation/t_SettingUpRuntimeUtilitiesOnOracleWebLogic.html)

If you are using WebLogic 12.1.3 (or later) and JDK 1.7, install the wlthint3client.jar file instead of wlfullclient.jar. If you are using WebLogic 12.1.3 (or later) and JDK 1.8 then install the wljmsclient.jar file and the wlclient.jar file and not wlfullclient.jar.

The jar you should use depends on the java you are using. In my case the wlclient.jar did not work and I got a **vmcid: SUN  minor code: 211** , so I changed wlthint3client.jar using java 8 with Oracle WebLogic Server 12.2.1.3 and now it worked for me.